# How do I set proxy in phantomjs

Tags: node.js, proxy, phantomjs

This https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom#functionality-details page says:

You can also pass command line switches to the phantomjs process by specifying additional args to phantom.create(), eg:

```
phantom.create '--load-images=no', '--local-to-remote-url-access=yes', (page) ->
```

or by specifying them in the **options*** object:

```
phantom.create {parameters: {'load-images': 'no', 'local-to-remote-url-access': 'yes'}}, (page) ->
```

These examples are only in coffee script and also they insinuate that the create function can take

```
create('string',function)
```

or

```
create([object object],function)
```

but really the first parameter expected is the function!

I really wanted to try http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html I might have the wrong idea but to me it looks like they can be used in the create function (right before you do the createPage), am I wrong?

I have tried several things, the most logical one is this:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
phantom.create(function(browser){
    browser.createPage(function(page){
        page.open('http://example.com/req.php', function() {

            });},{parameters:{'proxy':'98.239.198.83:21320'}});});
```

So the page gets opened. I know this because I am making req.php save the $_SERVER object to a txt pad but, the REMOTE_ADDR and REMOTE_PORT headers are not the ones in the proxy I have set. They have no effect. I have also tried:

```
{options:{'proxy':'98.239.198.83:21320'}}
```

As the docs call that object the **options*** object *see above^

and

```
'--proxy=98.239.198.83:21320'
```

I have also had a dig through the phantom module to find the create function. It is not written in js I can't see it at least. It must be in C++. It looks like this module has been updated but, the examples deep inside the module look like old code.

How do I do this?

**EDIT:**

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
phantom.create(function(browser){
    browser.createPage(function(page){

    browser.setProxy('98.239.198.83','21320','http', null, null, function(){

    page.open(
        'http://example.com/req.php', function() {

         });});});});
```

This produces no error and the page gets scraped but the proxy is ignored.

Comment: Proxy settings are set during process creation, not during page opening. Have you actually tried to pass the string or the object as the first parameter to `phantom.create`? How do you verify that the proxy setting doesn't work?

Comment: passing string as first param for the page.create gives error (expected function), I tried as you sugested to put it on phantom.create instead (tried before and after the function), no errors but it has no effect. I am not seen as being on a proxy

Comment: Is it a socks5 proxy?

Comment: I think it is a http proxy from http://www.us-proxy.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{ parameters: { 'proxy': 'socks://98.239.198.83:21320' } }
```

They didn't update their docs.

Comment: What docs are you talking about? `http` is the default setting in the docs under `--proxy-type`: http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html

Comment: node-phantom  .. the methods --proxy=192.168.1.42:8080 --proxy-type=[http|socks5|none] have been combined in parameters, I saw on a long discussion.

Comment: What about proxy auth params?

Answer (score 6):

As for as phantom 2.0.10 version the following code is running very well in my windows machine

```
  phantom.create(["--proxy=201.172.242.184:15124", "--proxy-type=socks5"])
      .then((instance) => {
          phInstance = instance;
          return instance.createPage();
      })
      .then((page) => {
          sitepage = page;
          return page.open('http://newsdaily.online');
      })
      .then((status) => {
          console.log(status);
          return sitepage.property('title');
      })
      .then((content) => {
          console.log(content);
          sitepage.close();
          phInstance.exit();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          phInstance.exit();
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

Time is going on, so PhantomJS now able to set proxy "on the fly" (even on per-page-basis): see this commit: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/commit/efd8dedfb574c15ddaac26ae72690fc2031e6749

Here is sample usage of new setProxy function (i did not find web page setting usage, this is general usage of proxy on instance of phantom):

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/openurlwithproxy.js

If you want per-page proxy, use full URL for proxy (schema, user name,password, host, port - all it the URL)

Answer (score 2):

As a side effect of trying to figure out an [issue on Github for phantomjs-nodejs](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node/issues/345) I was able to set a proxy as follows:

```
phantom = require 'phantom'
parameters = {
    loadimages: '--load-images=no',
    websecurity: '--web-security=no',
    ignoresslerrors: '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes',
    proxy: '--proxy=10.0.1.235:8118',
}
urls = {
    checktor: "https://check.torproject.org/",
    google: "https://google.com",
}
        
phantom.create parameters.websecurity, parameters.proxy, (ph) ->
  ph.createPage (page) ->
    page.open urls.checktor, (status) ->
      console.log "page opened? ", status
      page.evaluate (-> document.title), (result) ->
        console.log 'Page title is ' + result
        ph.exit()
```

The result where the proxy uses Tor was:

> page opened?  success
>
> Page title is Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor.

Answer (score 2):

use phantom npm package and co npm package.

```
co(function*() {
  const phantomInstance = yield phantom.create(["--proxy=171.13.36.64:808"]);
  crawScheduler.start(phantomInstance);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm running PhantomJS from windows cmd and syntaxes  it use looks bit different from what's I notice if you didn't put `http://` PJ wont recognize the value this is complete example

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.settings.loadImages = false;  //    
page.settings.proxy = 'http://192.168.1.5:8080' ; 
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36';
page.open('http://some.com/page', function() {
  page.render('some.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution for nodejs:

```js
const phantomInstance = await require('phantom').create();
const page = await phantomInstance.createPage();

// get current settings:
var pageSettings = await page.property('settings');
/*
{
  XSSAuditingEnabled: false,
  javascriptCanCloseWindows: true,
  javascriptCanOpenWindows: true,
  javascriptEnabled: true,
  loadImages: true,
  localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled: false,
  userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) ... PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1',
  webSecurityEnabled: true
}
*/

pageSettings.proxy = 'https://78.40.87.18:808';

// update settings (return value is undefined):
await page.property('settings', pageSettings);

const status = await page.open('https://2ip.ru/');

// show IP:
var ip = await page.evaluate(function () {
    var el = document.getElementById('d_clip_button');
    return !el ? '?' : el.textContent;
});
console.log('IP:', ip);
```

It's an option to set proxy within specific page.

Answer (score 0):

The CoffeeScript example is a little strange, because it is the `browser` that is passed into the callback of `phantom.create` and not `page`, but otherwise it must be compatible judging by the [code](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node/blob/b49daee7f551ee46da7f9e2547d83ee7216c9b0e/phantom.js#L68).

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
phantom.create({
    parameters: {
        proxy: '98.239.198.83:21320'
    }
}, function(browser){
    browser.createPage(function(page){
        page.open('http://example.com/req.php', function() {
            ...
        });
    });
});
```

Proxy settings are set during process creation, not during page opening. Although PhantomJS contains an undocumented `phantom.setProxy()` function which enables you to change the proxy settings in the middle of the script. The phantom module also seems to [support it](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node/blob/b49daee7f551ee46da7f9e2547d83ee7216c9b0e/shim.js#L5630).

Comment: just tried this but It doesn't work. the page loads but the proxy is ignored

Comment: I just noticed your link points to phantomjs-node which is different from the package.json of the one I have> https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs

Comment: just installed the one youve got but no change, very strange

Comment: You're using the `phantom` npm package which points to the repository I was referencing. The `phantomjs` npm package on the other hand is the actual PhantomJS executable and not the bridge.

Comment: So what should I be using, I am very confused?
phantom.setProxie('98.239.198.83','21320','http');

TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setProxie'

Comment: Well, it is `setProxy('98.239.198.83','21320','http', null, null, function(){page.open...})`

Comment: just tried this and both the page and phantom objects have no method 'setProxy'. see my edit^

Comment: lol just tried browser  browser.setProxy('98.239.198.83','21320','http', null, null, function(){ this does not produce an error (the page gets scraped but the proxy is ignored)

Comment: browser.set('proxy','98.239.198.83:21320'); does not do anything eather

Answer (score -1):

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
phantom.create(function (browser) {
    browser.setProxy(proxyIP, proxyPort);
    page.open(url, function (status) {
        console.log(status);
    });
},{dnodeOpts:{weak: false}});
```

it works fine on my windows.